# Visual c++ compile error when make HTTP request

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi, visual-c++

Here SendPost() will send a HTTP GET request to a server. When I used to compile this code snippet its showing that " error C2275: 'HINTERNET' : illegal use of this type as an expression ". I included "wininet.h" at the beginning of the program even though it showing errors.

```
void SendPost(TCHAR *szName, TCHAR *szNumber, YACINFO *yi)
{
TCHAR szText[128], szLogText[256], szFormat[256];
GetDateTimeString(szText, 128);

LoadString(yi->hinst, IDS_INCOMING_CALL_HEADER, szFormat, 256);
_snprintf(szLogText, 256, szFormat, szText);

LoadString(yi->hinst, IDS_LOGFILE_NAME, szFormat, 256);
_snprintf(szLogText, 256, szFormat, szName);

LoadString(yi->hinst, IDS_LOGFILE_NUMBER, szFormat, 256);
_snprintf(szLogText, 256, szFormat, szNumber);

MessageBox(NULL,szNumber,"Status",MB_OK);


HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("Utility", 0,NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET hOpenUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hSession,"http://www.ourwebsite.com/index.php?sender=123&&receiver=124&&msgdata=sample SMS today&&recvtime=01:12&&msgid=123458", NULL,0, 1, 1);

if( hOpenUrl == NULL){
//invalid URL
}
InternetCloseHandle(hOpener);
InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
        MessageBox(NULL,"Request Send","Status",MB_OK);


}
```

Comment: Which line is the compile error?

Comment: And - does it work with a simpler URL?  Is there something unescaped in that URL that is confusing the compiler?

Comment: Error showing on line starting with "HINTERNET hSession". Its does not even compiling.

Answer (score 0):

```
HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("Utility", 0,NULL, NULL, 0);
HINTERNET hOpenUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hSession,"http://www.ourwebsite.com/index.php?sender=123&&receiver=124&&msgdata=sample SMS today&&recvtime=01:12&&msgid=123458", NULL,0, 1, 1);

if( hOpenUrl == NULL){
//invalid URL
}

InternetCloseHandle(hOpener);
InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
MessageBox(NULL,"Request Send","Status",MB_OK);
```

I can successfully compile this on VS2010.  I'm guessing it's either an issue with code formatting (e.g. a missing brace) or something else.

Comment: Then you have a problem somewhere else.  This builds on 2008 as well.  I would be looking for syntax errors in your header files, possibly missing braces or semicolons.